# Positioning of location markers on top of location?

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, artoolkit

I followed the above tutorial ([link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based)) to make a sample app which will show markers depending upon the location coordinates for the objects(like a building) .I'm able to show my custom markers on the given location .But markers are floating around the location.How can fix my marker to show on the top of the building .?

Any suggestion or advice...

Thanks in advance!!!!!!

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik thanks for edting

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely due to sensor jitter. Gyroscopes usually don't provide an stable reading.

I suggest you do a rolling average of the values and also add thresholds for minimum variation.